# Encrypting XML database in python

Tags: python, xml, encryption, lxml

i am using XML as my backend for the application...

LXML is used to parse the xml.

How can i encrypt this xml file to make sure that the data is protected......

thanks in advance.

Comment: you're missing the R in Encrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As XML contains repetitive structure it is better to first `compress` and then `encrypt` it.

Download and install [PyDes](http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html).

```
from pyDes import *
import bz2

def encrypt(data,password):
    k = des(password, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
    d = k.encrypt(data)
    return d

def decrypt(data,password):
    k = des(password, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
    d = k.decrypt(data)
    return d

password = "eight222" # password length should be 8

data = '''
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <library>
   <shelf id="fiction">
    <book>
     <title>Of Mice and Men</title>
     <author>John Steinbeck</author>
    </book>
    <book>
     <title>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</title>
     <author>J.K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
   </shelf>
  </library> 
'''

print len(data)

compressed_data = bz2.compress(data)
print len(compressed_data)

encrypted_data = encrypt(compressed_data,password)

print "%r"%encrypted_data

uncompressed_encrypted_data = encrypt(data,password)

print len(encrypted_data)
print len(uncompressed_encrypted_data)
print bz2.decompress(decrypt(encrypted_data,password))
```

There are lots of cryptography libraries available in python

1. [Pure-Python RSA implementation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa/1.3.1)
2. [Python Encryption Examples](http://www.example-code.com/python/encryption.asp)
3. [PyXMLSec](http://pyxmlsec.labs.libre-entreprise.org/)
4. [PyCrypto - The Python Cryptography Toolkit](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/)

Comment: i think hashlib is irreversible...
i need a reversible one

Comment: after decrypting we will get the data as a string. right????
then how can i parse that string xml with lxml library????